# fix javascript discrepancies with two javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm not good in javascript and I have:

```
jQuery Skitter Slideshow ver. 4.2.1 by Thiago Silva Ferreira - http://thiagosf.net / Ex: http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/
```

and

```
jCarousel - Riding carousels with jQuery by Jan Sorgalla http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
```

javascript and working fine but when i add this script i have problem how can i fix it:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tabmeslect li:first").addClass("selected");
    $("#sideme > div").hide();
    $("#sideme > div:first").show();
    $("#tabmeslect a").click(function(){
        $("#tabmeslect li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        var a=$(this).attr("href");
        $("#sideme > div:visible").hide();
        $(a).fadeToggle(1000);
        return false;
    })
});
```

and i get error when add this script above

```
Uncaught Error: jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...
```

but when i delete it it work fine how can fix this javascript????.

Thank you advance

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your jCarousel with:

```
jQuery('#theCarousel').jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    visible: 1,
    animation: 3000,
    auto: 8,
    wrap: 'circular',
    itemFallbackDimension: 300
});
```

or edit:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#tabmeslect li:first").addClass("selected");
    jQuery("#sideme > div").hide();
    jQuery("#sideme > div:first").show();
    jQuery("#tabmeslect a").click(function(){
        jQuery("#tabmeslect li").removeClass("selected");
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("selected");
        var a=jQuery(this).attr("href");
        jQuery("#sideme > div:visible").hide();
        jQuery(a).fadeToggle(1000);
        return false;
    })
});
```

note above that I have changed the `$` to `jQuery` to make sure your includes are not overriting your `$`.

Comment: thank you but not only jcarousel and Skitter Slideshow

Comment: @user2821185, I wouldn't know what `the script not work` means.. we would need some more information or a URL to see for ourselves..